# Django complex queries

Tags: python, sql, django, model, date

I need to craft a filter for an object that checks date ranges. Right now I'm performing a very inefficient loop which checks all the objects. I would like to simplify this to a database call.

The logic is you have a `start` and an `end` date objects. I need to check if the start OR the end is within the range of an appointment.

```
if (start >= appointment.start && start < appointment.end) || 
   (end > appointment.start && end <= appointment.end)
```

I could do this in SQL, but I'm not as familiar with the Django model structure for more complex queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Q objects for & and OR operators and the `range` field lookup type

Q Object: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

range: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range

```
Entry.objects.filter(Q(start__range=(appointment.start, appointment.end)) | 
    Q(end__range=(appointment.start, appointment.end)))
```

If an SQL `BETWEEN`, is not what you are looking for, you can always use specific combinations of Q objects to reproduce your conditions exactly:

```
Entry.objects.filter((Q(start__gte=appointment.start) & Q(start__lt=appointment.end)) | 
   (Q(end__gt=appointment.start) & Q(end__lte=appointment.end)))
```

Comment: Using the first example, where do you use `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: Sorry Josh! The initial example was straight from the docs, and then in a later update I adopted your specific variables :) I will remove those